# Custom JComponent to set preferred scrollable viewport size

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, preferredsize, jviewport

So I am trying to create a custom component so I can set the size of my scroll pane. Here is the part with the scroll pane:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(leftTop);
customScroll t1 = new customScroll();
scrollPane.add(t1);
left.add(scrollPane);
```

leftTop is a nested panel inside of left. Here is my class for customScroll which is the custom component I am making so I can set the size of the scroll pane:

```
public class customScroll extends JComponent implements Scrollable {

    public customScroll() {
        getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return(new Dimension(266,300));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
            int orientation, int direction) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
            int orientation, int direction) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I set the preferred scrollable size?

Comment: Please pay attention to Java naming conventions - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html - Especially class names ; Also, mention what exact issue are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a setter...

```
public void setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(Dimension size) {
    this.preferredScrollableViewportSize = size;
}
```

Now, obviously, your `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` will need to return this value...

```
public class CustomScroll extends JComponent implements Scrollable {

    private Dimension preferredScrollableViewportSize = new Dimension(266, 300);

    public CustomScroll() {
    }

    public void setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(Dimension size) {
        this.preferredScrollableViewportSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return preferredScrollableViewportSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                    int orientation, int direction) {
        return 64;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                    int orientation, int direction) {
        return 64;
    }
}
```

Should also set this before you wrap in your `JScrollPane`, it would just be easier to manage, otherwise, you'll need `invalidate` the container in which the `JScrollPane` resides

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

> But that will still just get the preferred size

No it won't, it will use the `preferredScrollableViewportSize` (assuming you're wrapping in within a `JScrollPane`

> my scroll pane adjusts to what is in it so it just grows with buttons added

Then you're doing something wrong

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(leftTop);    
customScroll t1 = new customScroll();
// This is wrong...
scrollPane.add(t1);
left.add(scrollPane);
```

You should never add anything to a `JScrollPane`, it's not how they work, instead, you need to wrap the component within it

```
leftTop t1 = new CustomScroll();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(leftTop);    
left.add(scrollPane);
```

Or some such...

> I want it to remain a fixed size so I need to explicitly set a size that it cannot deviate from

Yes, that's what `preferredScrollableViewportSize` is doing

[image: ExampleLayout]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication57 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication57();
    }

    public JavaApplication57() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            CustomScroll comp = new CustomScroll();
            comp.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

            comp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 10, 5);
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {

                JButton btn = new JButton("Hello world " + index);
                comp.add(btn, gbc);

            }

            add(new JScrollPane(comp));
        }

    }

    public class CustomScroll extends JComponent implements Scrollable {

        private Dimension preferredScrollableViewportSize = new Dimension(266, 300);

        public CustomScroll() {
        }

        public void setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(Dimension size) {
            this.preferredScrollableViewportSize = size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return preferredScrollableViewportSize;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                        int orientation, int direction) {
            return 64;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                        int orientation, int direction) {
            return 64;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But that will still just get the preferred size, my scroll pane adjusts to what is in it so it just grows with buttons added. I want it to remain a fixed size so I need to explicitly set a size that it cannot deviate from.

Comment: nvm I am retarded and cant read the docs page. +1 for your answer though lol.